# wordpress troubleshooting of custom shortcode where no content is displayed

Tags: wordpress

I have this custom shortcode in my functions.php and I'm calling it with `[landingpage]Some content here[/landingpage]` through the wordpress backend.

```
add_shortcode('landingpage', function ($atts, $content = NULL, $tag = NULL) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts(['post_id' => 0], $atts, $tag);

    if (empty($atts['post_id']) || empty($post = get_post($atts['post_id']))) {
        return ''; // return nothing, a proper post_id was not passed by the user
    }

    ob_start();
    ?>
    <h2>Title: <?= $post->post_title ?></h2>
    <p><?= $content ?: $post->post_excerpt ?></p>
    <p><a href="<?= get_permalink($post->ID) ?>">Read More</a></p>
    <?php
    return ob_get_clean();
});
```

I made a custom page template with the following code

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Landingpage
 */

get_header(); ?>

<div class="col kb_landing_left">
    <?= do_shortcode('[landingpage post_id="56"]') ?>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <?php foreach ([1, 86, 88] as $post_id) : ?>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col kb_landing_right">
                <?= do_shortcode("[landingpage post_id='{$post_id}']") ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>

<?php
get_footer();
```

The title and the "Read More" (with redirecting to the correct post) are displayed. But the content itself is missing entirely. For debugging purposes, i added a string to see if the ID submission is faulty:

```
 if (empty($atts['post_id']) || empty($post = get_post($atts['post_id']))) {
        return 'post_id is missing'; // return nothing, a proper post_id was not passed by the user
    }
```

This isn't displaying as well, so the IDs were submitted.

I have some plugins installed, so deactivated all of them to ensure the issue isn't related to those. Nothing has changed.

Some general information; I'm using the Bootstrap 4 Starter theme, respectively i made a child theme of it. Everything else is working as it should. I can't tell what's wrong with the shortcode not displaying the post content.

Any help is much appreciated!

Here is the ourput of var_dump($post);

```
object(WP_Post)#8044 (24) {
  ["ID"]=>
  int(56)
  ["post_author"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["post_date"]=>
  string(19) "2020-06-24 22:56:11"
  ["post_date_gmt"]=>
  string(19) "2020-06-24 22:56:11"
  ["post_content"]=>
  string(591) "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet."
  ["post_title"]=>
  string(6) "Test 2"
  ["post_excerpt"]=>
  string(20) "some excerpt content"
  ["post_status"]=>
  string(7) "publish"
  ["comment_status"]=>
  string(4) "open"
  ["ping_status"]=>
  string(4) "open"
  ["post_password"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["post_name"]=>
  string(4) "test"
  ["to_ping"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["pinged"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["post_modified"]=>
  string(19) "2020-07-07 21:34:30"
  ["post_modified_gmt"]=>
  string(19) "2020-07-07 21:34:30"
  ["post_content_filtered"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["post_parent"]=>
  int(0)
  ["guid"]=>
  string(31) "https://wiki.fiveseven.ch/?p=56"
  ["menu_order"]=>
  int(0)
  ["post_type"]=>
  string(4) "post"
  ["post_mime_type"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["comment_count"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["filter"]=>
  string(3) "raw"
}
```

Comment: For sure in your example `$content` will be `NULL` since your call to the shortcode does not have content passed to it like `[landingpage post_id="56"]some content[/landingpage]`. I suspect your `$post->post_excerpt` is an empty string as well. If that is the case then your code is working as expected, but you may want out output something else like `get_the_content(null, false, $post)`, etc instead. But first, to debug my hypothesis, to please add `<?php var_dump($post); ?>` above `<p><?= $content ?: $post->post_excerpt ?></p>`, and post it's output(s) at the end of your question.

Comment: @Phil, thank you for getting back to me. I just realized, that you mean the dedicated excerpt box in the backend... if i put some text in there, it shows up. However, the actual content ist still missing. I added the var_dump funtion as you suggested and the output is at the end of my question.

Well, content is visible there (and the excerpt), but if i remove the var_dump funtion again, only the exerpt remains displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your updated note and var_dump results, it looks to me like everything is/was working as it should. You just needed to add the excerpt text in the admin, as you figured out. But it sounds like you want a different result to display. Based on what I'm reading, you don't really want the `$content` that is passed to the shortcode (which would always be an empty string in your specific scenario), rather you want the content of the actual post. So here are a few options to choose and test to see which ones you are right for you.

If you want to show the full content (however long it may be). Use:

```php
<div><?= get_the_content(null, false, $post) ?></div>
```

If you want to show the excerpt (and fallback to the truncated post content with ellipsis if the excerpt happens to be empty). Use:

```php
<p><?= get_the_excerpt($post) ?></p>
```

If you like the idea of the truncated post content, like in `get_the_excerpt($post)`, but you definitely don't want the excerpt to show up, even if it exists. Use:

```php
<p><?= wp_trim_excerpt('', $post) ?></p>
// NOTE: the first agrument MUST be a an empty string ''
```

If you want to stick with the content the user is passing via the shortcode tag (you probably don't want this, but I'm adding it here for others). Use:

```php
<p><?= $content ?></p>
```

However, if you really do want this, you'll need to pass it in your Landingpage template. Something like this: `[landingpage post_id="56"]some content[/landingpage]` or `[landingpage post_id='{$post_id}']some content[/landingpage]`

You can also fallback to any one of these with the shorten ternary operation `?:` as is in your original question.

Try these options to see which one works for your needs. Remember (other than the last example I had) if you still see an empty string for a the content, then `<?php var_dump($post); ?>` again to make sure that post actually has content to display. For the last example you'd need to add `<?php var_dump($content); ?>` to see if the $content is being passed inside the do_shortcode() call. Hope that helps!

Comment: Awesome, now everything is much more clear to me. I will use `<?= get_the_content(null, false, $post) ?>`, it's the best solution. I want to thank you again for your paitence and the great support!

Answer (score 0):

Try to change ternary if

```
<p><?= get_the_excerpt($post) ?></p>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that unfortunately didn't fix the issue

Comment: I hope I found problem. I updated my answer. Please check

Comment: thanks for your help. The code works fine, but I'm trying to get a solution for the above, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the problem you have is in this line:

```
<p><?= $content ?: $post->post_excerpt ?></p>
```

As the title and the readme link are working, you should focus on this.

You are echoing a variable called `$content` but the variable is not defined anywhere in your function. So this is empty. You should do a definition first, or just write:

```
<p><?= $post->post_content ?: $post->post_excerpt ?></p>
```

If I got it the right way, this is (in my oppion) a not very readable if/else in which you want to check if the post content is empty. If it is empty, you want to display the post excerpt. I'm not sure if you are using the syntax the right way... here is what I found:

```
$action = (empty($_POST['action'])) ? 'standard' : $_POST['action'];
```

So there is an condition. If empty, use "standard", and if not empty, use "$_POST['action']".

You code should therefore look like:

```
(empty($post->post_content)) ? $post->post_excerpt : $post->post_content;
```

I would suggest making it more readable, especially for debugging reasons:

```
<h2>Title: <?= $post->post_title ?></h2>
<p>
<?php if(empty($post->post_content)) {
             echo $post->excerpt;
         } else {
             echo $post->post_content;
         } ?>
</p>
<p><a href="<?= get_permalink($post->ID) ?>">Read More</a></p>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. This code works partially, when i call the shortcode over my custom landingpage.php page template. But only the entire conten ist displayed, no excerpt. Of course i added a read more in the middle of the text in the backend. 

Using the shortcode through the Wordpress backend doesn't work at all. It's displaying the `[landingpage]` shortcode brackets, along with the text content.